# Call to a member function getmetavalue() on null

Tags: php, model-view-controller, laravel-5

I got an error when a database table is empty when my model's function calls it. This is my code in my AccountMeta model.

```
public function scopeGetmetavalue($query, $key){
    $data = $query->where('meta_key', '=', $key)->pluck('meta_value');
    if($data->count()){
        if(isset($data[0])){
            return $data[0];
        }
    }

    return " ";
}
```

This is on my views to call it:

```
$GroupFile = Auth::user()->account->meta->getmetavalue('file_group_contact');
```

My Database structure is this:

```
Schema::create('account_metas', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('account_id');
            $table->string('meta_key');
            $table->string('meta_value');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

There is no issue when there is data in the account_metas table but when it is empty I got the error. any idea of it?

Comment: elaborate more.. what are these `account` & `meta`  in the query? Do you have any relationships defined? what is the output of `dd(Auth::user()->account->meta)`

Comment: When there's no data in the table, `Auth::user()->account->meta` will return `null`. So a call to `Auth::user()->account->meta->getmetavalue('file_group_contact')` is bound to give you an _Exception_ as you are calling `getmetavalue()` on `null`. If you just want to ignore the _Exception_, then prefix the statement with an `@` symbol: `@Auth::user()->account->meta->getmetavalue('file_group_contact')`

Answer (score 0):

When there's no data in the table,
`Auth::user()->account->meta` will return `null`.
So a call to

```
Auth::user()->account->meta->getmetavalue('file_group_contact')
```

is bound to give you an *Exception* as you are calling `getmetavalue()` on `null`. If you just want to ignore the *Exception*, then prefix the statement with an `@` symbol:

```
 $GroupFile =  @Auth::user()->account->meta->getmetavalue('file_group_contact');
```

Now, when there's no data in the `table`, you'll have `$GroupFile` as `null` instead of getting an exception. You may then check the value of `$GroupFile` before proceeding with the code execution.

```
if($GroupFile) {
 // some code
}
```